# Image classification using flower dataset example

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-storage

I have attempted this example: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/flowers-tutorial . I was entering all the code into the Cloud Shell window. However, when I entered the following line:

python trainer/preprocess.py \
    --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
    --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
    --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
    --cloud

The cloud shell crashes/closes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to take into account while following this tutorial.

To start you should be sure that you have Cloud ML Engine API and the Dataflow API activated.

The robot service account: service-[project number]@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com should have access to your project. You can check it in your console in “IAM”.

On the Declaring Variables step it is really important that all the variables have the right value. I advise you to check the value of each variable before executing the Python script (using `echo $VARIABLE` the value of the variable will be showed in the console).

Note that every time the shell is closed you will need to install all the dependencies needed by the project, running the command :`sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`. One way to avoid this is setting up a isolated Python environment with virtualenv (you can get more information about it [here](http://cloud.google.com/python/setup)) then you just need to install the needed dependencies on that environment once.